# VB.NET MVC Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Create' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, startup, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using **VB.NET MVC 5** with **Identity 2.0**.

I've been trying to configure my Startup.Auth to automatically use a single instance of ApplicationDbContext, CustomUserManager and CustomRoleManager per request [as detailed in this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics#premain2).

My code is as follows: (minus garbage)

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create)
    ' Error 135 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'CreatePerOwinContext' can be called with these arguments:
    '   Extension method 'Public Function CreatePerOwinContext(Of T)(createCallback As System.Func(Of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions(Of T), Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext, T)) As Owin.IAppBuilder' defined in 'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
    '   Extension method 'Public Function CreatePerOwinContext(Of T)(createCallback As System.Func(Of T)) As Owin.IAppBuilder' defined in 'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of CustomUserManager)(CustomUserManager.Create)
    ' Error 136 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Create' accepts this number of arguments.
    ....
End Sub
```

But recieve these errors no matter what I do

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Create' accepts this number of arguments.

I think it's to do with me writing in VB and the example being in C#, though it infuriates me that this is a problem. My CustomUserManager is a Public Class, and the Create method is Public Shared.

```
Public Shared Function Create(options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of CustomUserManager), context As IOwinContext) As CustomUserManager
    Dim manager As CustomUserManager
    manager = New CustomUserManager(New CustomUserStore(context.Get(Of ApplicationDbContext)()))
    manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser, Integer)(manager)
    manager.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator() With {
        .RequiredLength = 6
    }
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode",
        New EmailTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser, Integer)() With {
            .Subject = "Security Code",
            .BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
        }
    )
    manager.EmailService = New EmailService()
    manager.SmsService = New SmsService()
    If Not options.DataProtectionProvider Is Nothing Then
        manager.UserTokenProvider = New DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser, Integer)(options.DataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
    End If
    Return manager
End Function
```

Any ideas anyone? Any help is much appreciated, Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
End Sub
```

The AddressOf operator creates a function delegate that points to the function specified by procedurename

[link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx)

[link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn612979(v=vs.108).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already updated your visual studio 2013 with Update 3. This comes with all the identity stuff and custom user manager, role manager and many more.

Create new project using MVC template and Authentication selected as Individual User Accounts using Visual Studio 2013. Then you will get created all the code same as you have already implemented using the example. You can use that classes and implementation in order to fix your issues with your custom user manager.

Check the floder App_Start >> IdentityConfig.vb

Only thing I can see in your code, you have used integer as Id rather than string. That won't be a problem if you have correctly bind EF model biding stuff.